# "The specified collections path is not part of the configured Ansible collections paths" but I'm installing into a relative directory

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-galaxy

I'm installing the `ansible.posix` collection to use in my playbook like this:

```
ansible-galaxy collection install -r ansible/requirements.yml -p ansible/collections
```

*However, I get this warning message that I want to get rid of:*

```
[WARNING]: The specified collections path '/home/myuser/path/to/my/repo/ansible/collections' is not part of the
configured Ansible collections paths '/home/myuser/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections'. The installed collection won't be
picked up in an Ansible run.
```

My repo is laid out like this:

```
├── ansible
│   ├── playbook.yml
│   ├── files
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── tasks
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── requirements.yml
├── ansible.cfg
...
```

`ansible.cfg` looks like this:

```
[defaults]
timeout = 60
callback_whitelist = profile_tasks
```

Here's the output of `ansible --version`:

```
ansible 2.9.17
  config file = /home/myuser/path/to/my/repo/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/myuser/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44) [GCC 8.3.0]
```

In [the docs for installing collections with `ansible-galaxy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/collections_using.html#installing-collections-with-ansible-galaxy), they say the following:

> You can also keep a collection adjacent to the current playbook, under a `collections/ansible_collections/` directory structure.
>
> ```
> play.yml
> ├── collections/
> │   └── ansible_collections/
> │               └── my_namespace/
> │                   └── my_collection/<collection structure lives here>
> ```

And, like the documentation suggests, I can still use the collection just fine in my play. But this warning message is quite annoying. **How do I get rid of it?**

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: @E3G nope, still no idea how to resolve it. I've just started ignoring the message

Answer (score 5):

I have created `ansible.cfg` within the ansible project I'm working on.
You could simply `cp /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg .`
but since the file would look like:

```
[defaults]
collections_paths = ./collections/ansible_collections
```

It is just easier to create it.
Once there, Ansible will know about your custom configuration file.

In you project folder you will:
`mkdir -p ./collections/ansible_collections`
And then run the install.

If your `requirements.yml` contains a collection like:

```
collections:
  - community.general
```

You'd have to install it as:
`ansible-galaxy collection install -r requirements.yml -p ./collections/`

And the output would be:

```
[borat@mypotatopc mycoolproject]$ ansible-galaxy collection install -r requirements.yml -p ./collections/
Process install dependency map
Starting collection install process
Installing 'community.general:3.1.0' to '/home/borat/projects/mycoolproject/collections/ansible_collections/community/general'
```

In case you won't setup your modified `ansible.cfg`, the output would be:

```
[borat@mypotatopc mycoolproject]$ ansible-galaxy collection install -r requirements.yml -p ./
[WARNING]: The specified collections path '/home/borat/projects/mycoolproject' is not part of the configured Ansible collections paths
'/home/borat/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections'. The installed collection won't be picked up in an Ansible run.
Process install dependency map
Starting collection install process
Installing 'community.general:3.1.0' to '/home/borat/projects/mycoolproject/ansible_collections/community/general'
```

There are other methods too, but I like this one.

Comment: It looks like should be just: `collections_paths = collections` in the `ansible.cfg`